# State variables in Property Wrappers

Tags: swift

I would like to use a variable to cache user defaults which are fetched by a propert wrapper. I used the boilerplate from this quite good tutorial regarding property wrappers as a basis https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/property-wrappers/

```
@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: T
    @State var cacheValue: T?

    init(_ key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            if (self.cacheValue == nil){
               self.cacheValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
            }
            return self.cacheValue
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

During debugging I found out that my cacheValue always returns nil, even if there is a corresponding user  property value that is returned.

So the question is: Are @State variables supposed to work in property wrapppers? And if not, is there a workaround, that does not mean coding it in the class/struct that uses the property wrapper construct?

Answer (score 1):

`@State` is a property wrapper declared inside `SwiftUI` and it should only be used inside `View`s.

Comment: Understood, so I cannot use the @State annotation inside a property wrapper, since it is not a view. But is there any "good" workaround for this problem?